# jupyter notebook Resource warning, unclosed socket error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

error:
`sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed socket <zmq.Socket(zmq.PUSH) at 0x26e1c8709a0> C:\Users\knnid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\_process_win32.py:145: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedWriter name=4> C:\Users\knnid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\_process_win32.py:145: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=5> C:\Users\knnid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\_process_win32.py:145: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.BufferedReader name=6>`

code for which the above error is output:

```
!pip install csvkit
import csvkit
import pandas as pd


with open('train.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csvkit.DictReader(file)
    data = [row for row in reader]


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Dataframe to be created and after which we could contents of dataframe using :
print(df)

Comment: I find that very difficult to believe.  WHERE did you get that error, exactly?  What had you done?  Did you try to kill the process?

Comment: i commented this part
 !pip install csvkit
import csvkit
import pandas as pd
and it worked fine , ig as i ran the code multiple times, re installing the packages and re-importing of libraries used to happen